# what is group/edit, group/item means in tailwindcss doc

Tags: web, frontend, tailwind-css

i've been learning tailwind css and i stuck at styling based on parent state

```
<li class="group/item hover:bg-slate-100 ...">
  <img src="{person.imageUrl}" alt="" />
  <div>
    <a href="{person.url}">{person.name}</a>
    <p>{person.title}</p>
  </div>
  <a class="group/edit invisible hover:bg-slate-200 group-hover/item:visible ..." href="tel:           {person.phone}">
    <span class="group-hover/edit:text-gray-700 ...">Call</span>
    <svg class="group-hover/edit:translate-x-0.5 group-hover/edit:text-slate-500 ...">
      <!-- ... -->
    </svg>
  </a>
</li>
```

i've confused on what is group/item means in li class, group/edit in a class, group-hover/item:visible, and lastly kind of group-hover/edit:text-gray-700.

can someone explain to me what is those means?
here's the link to the tailwind doc
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state

Answer (score 1):

[As per the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-nested-groups):

> When nesting groups, you can style something based on the state of a *specific* parent group by giving that parent a unique group name using a `group/{name}` class, and including that name in modifiers using classes like `group-hover/{name}`:

So `group-hover/item:visible` applies `visibility: visible` when a parent element that has the class `group/item` is hovered.

`group-hover/edit:text-gray-700` applies `color: theme(colors.gray.700)` when a parent element that has the class `group/edit` is hovered.